# Why is Express rendering a page other than specified in res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to render an ejs page called compare.ejs but when I navigate to the page where i am expecting compare to be rendered, another page has been rendered. What am I missing here?

in app.js :

```
var compare = require('./routes/compare')(nav);
app.use('/compare', compare);
```

in routes/compare.js

```
var compare = express.Router();

var router = function (nav) {
    compare.route('/')
        .get(function(req,res){
            res.render('compare',
                      {
                nav: nav
            })
    });
return compare
};
module.exports = router;
```

However when I navigate to /compare another page with another name is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have another route before `compare` that is matching the same location. Remember that the routes are `middleware` so, you must be careful with the order.

Comment: Thanks, This is the problem. I was using this:

     app.use('/', politicians); 

before my compare router.
Can you elaborate as to why '/' is used when I at '/compare'

Answer (score 1):

Might need to be router.route() rather than compare.route()

// after edit

This sort of thing usually happens if an earlier route matches the same route.  Do you have other, similar routes?

Comment: Sorry I should have included that I have this in my compare router as well.

 var compare = express.Router();

Comment: Yes as I added to the Answer above I was using this: app.use('/', politicians); before my compare router. I am still interested as to why '/' is considered a matching route to '/compare'. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should order your routes from most specific to least specific.  This is because it takes the first that satisfies the constraint.  '/compare' starts with '/', so it matches in your case; it's a pattern, not an explicit match, if that makes sense.